# How to retrieve data from the DB for recursively binding a jquery treeview using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table structure like this.

```
id | Name | ParentId
```

so for example:

```
id | Name     | ParentId 
------------------------- 
1  | Alice    | 0 
2  | Bob      | 0 
3  | Charlie  | 1 
4  | David    | 2
```

where 'Alice' and 'Bob' are Parent nodes( which has Id = 0) and Alice has a child node named  'Charlie' and 'Bob' has a child node named 'David'. My question is, I need to retrieve the parent separately and the children in a collection. The 'Children' collection can have multiple parents and its children. Can anyone send me a code snippet using which I can retrieve Data from the database and populate the tree.

Comment: Which treeview control are you using? The default that ships with ASP.NET or a jQuery treeview plugin?

Comment: I see you edited the question. Even for jquery my code should be valid (with slight modification).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [How to populate treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184115/how-to-populate-treeview/3184794#3184794) except the classes used will be from the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace (they are named the same).

Also `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` methods don't exist for obvious reasons.

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to use server controls in a asp.net mvc application. And this task is (at least in my opinion) a lot easier without server controls.