# c# populate treeview from LINQ object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a linq object that i'm trying to fill a treeview from using c# winforms.

Sample

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3        
Test 1     Item A     Sub Item 1      
Test 1     Item A     Sub Item 2      
Test 1     Item A     Sub Item 3      
Test 1     Item B     Sub Item 1      
Test 1     Item B     Sub Item 2     
Test 1     Item B     Sub Item 3
```

And fill the treeview like

```
Test 1 (CheckBox)
------Item A (CheckBox)
-------------Sub Item 1  (CheckBox)
-------------Sub Item 2  (CheckBox)
-------------Sub Item 3  (CheckBox)
------Item B (CheckBox)
-------------Sub Item 1  (CheckBox)
-------------Sub Item 2  (CheckBox)
-------------Sub Item 3  (CheckBox)
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks
Sp

Comment: I see a lot of text that appears to be formatted for DOS.  Can you please post some C# (the LINQ you said you wrote).  Have you tried the winforms treeview control?

Comment: i am using a winforms control but am unable to get the object to show properly

Comment: Better design to have table with ID, ParentID, Name fields and use recursion to fill treeview. Examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184115/how-to-populate-treeview?rq=1), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814466/how-to-dynamically-populate-treeview-c?lq=1) and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you perform the following query:

```
var query = data.GroupBy(item => item.Column1)
                .Select(group => group.GroupBy(item => item.Column2))
                .Select(group => group.Select(innerGroup => 
                    innerGroup.GroupBy(item => item.Column3)));
```

You will have all of the items grouped first by column1, then 2 and 3, so It's already in a tree structure.  Now you just need to have 3 nested `for` loops to add the items to the treeview.

```
foreach (var outermostGroup in query)
{
    //add node for outermostGroup's key
    foreach (var middleGroup in outermostGroup)
    {
        //add child node of the above node for middleGroup key
        foreach (var innerGroup in middleGroup)
        {
            //add child node of the above node for innerGroup key
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly this code only works if there are a fixed number of columns with a fixed (max) depth.  If you don't know the number of columns and can have an arbitrary depth then you'd need a fairly radically different approach.