# (LINQ) populate treeview from very basic level

Tags: c#, linq, treeview

I just started to use linq to select data and populate treeview with the data.
Please let me know from the basic level...

This is what I did so far.

1. I connected to DB server. Drag from Tables list, so I can see the table that I need to use from right place. (DataClasses1.dbml)
2. How do I select data from the table by using linq?

I was trying to imitate [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128834/linq-to-populate-treeview-based-upon-grouping)

But I get the following error: **"could not find the implementation of the query pattern for the source type"**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
            var grped = 
                 from a in MyTable
                 group a by a.MyColumn into grp
                 select grp;
            var treeView = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();

            //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have populated DB data into `MyTable` (It should be a `Collection` that supports LINQ for example an `IEnumerable`) and want to group them by `MyColumn`:

Variable `grped` has the groups of `MyTable` data grouped by `MyColumn`.

Then iterate through the `grped` groupings and populate `TreeView` with each groups KEY (That is DISTINCT values of `MyColumn` data) as parent node and each grouped sub elements as the parent node's children.

I suspect `MyTable` is not in a form that can be used with LINQ. Also check you have the following directive `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Is there anything to populate DB data into MyTable? I just connected to database and MyTable is just one of the table name.

above my coding is not working. Error at 'from a in Mytable'

Comment: Follow these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943772.aspx AND http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0y4a0f6.aspx

Comment: How did you connect to database?

Comment: at 'Server Explorer' of Visual Studio.
So now I have DataClasses1.dbml in my Solution Explorer

Comment: I assume you are trying LINQ to SQL. You should get DataContext object to get the data into your application. Follow this link to get DataContext. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384470.aspx

Comment: Did you find the links or the answer useful?